# How to iterate through Array and remove an item based off a string value

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift3

I have a string with is a prefix. I'm iterating over an Array of String and if the value contains the prefix then I want to remove that item from the `Array`. My code is giving me the error:

> fatal error: Index out of range.

I need some direction on how to handle something like this.

```
for (index, value) in arrayValues.enumerated() {
    if value.contains(prefixValue)  {
        arrayValues.remove(at: index)
     }
}
```

Comment: How is your arrayValues defined?

Comment: var arrayValues = JSON["array"] as? [String] , I'm downloading this form an API

Comment: And `print(arrayValues)` output is?

Comment: ["rehjileo", "rehjhzse", "rehjlsid", "uvhydtkc", "rehjxeyl", "dyxejbrq", "rehjknwz", "rehjrewz", "rehjqlam", "ynabgzuq", "rehjpfbv", "pvuaokhl", "rehjzhlv", "rehjwxhj", "chfmptev", "ixgabfwj", "mvhnkusg", "lvfcipnt", "rehjlhrn", "rehjiosy"]

Comment: Which swift version are you using man!?

Comment: var filterArray = arrayValues.filter { !$0.lowercased().contains(prefixValue) }
worked for this solution.

Comment: Swift3 is the version I have

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you try to use `filter` for that.

```
var filterArray = arrayValues.filter { !$0.contains(prefixValue) }
```

For case insensitive Swift 3

```
var filterArray = arrayValues.filter { !$0.lowercased().contains(prefixValue) }
```

For case insensitive Swift 2.3 or lower

```
var filterArray = arrayValues.filter { !$0.lowercaseString.contains(prefixValue) }
```

**Edit :** I have `filter` the array with `contains` because OP have asked question with contains but for some reason others are thinking that this is the wrong answer. So now I'm adding `filter` also with `hasPrefix`.

```
var filterArray = arrayValues.filter { !$0.lowercased().hasPrefix(prefixValue) }
```

Comment: Welcome mate :)

Comment: This will filter the strings containing `reh` anywhere in it.

Comment: @Mr.UB I have given the answer on the basis of op question that is the reason I have used contains.

Comment: @Mr.UB, Nirav D is right, the question says "if the value contains the prefix" instead of "if the value starts with the prefix". It might be simply bad phrasing but this is technically the correct answer. (The best kind of answer...)

Comment: @Mr.UB As of people like you thinking that this is wrong answer I have updated the answer also with `hasPrefix`.

Comment: @ColGraff Thanks for understanding the my answer, also I have edited answer, I hope down voters at least read the answer before down voting.

Comment: I hope my down-vote cleared out all the confusion, it is better said than being quiet, so I did. And this: `simply bad phrasing` caught me.

Comment: @Mr.UB But before down voting at least read the question.

Comment: _People have different opinions, Down-vote and comment section are meant for something, I just didn't randomly down-voted and went away, rather I commented the reason too_. Now the things are clear and I removed the down-vote. Happy Hunting :)

Comment: @Mr.UB  I think i have also clear answer now, Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

To be more explicit with the type of comparison you are doing I'd use the `hasPrefix` or `range` methods:

```
import Foundation

let foo = "test"
let arrayValues = ["Testy", "tester", "Larry", "testing", "untested"]

// hasPrefix is case-sensitive
let filterArray = arrayValues.filter {
  $0.hasPrefix(foo)
}

print(filterArray) // -> "["tester", "testing"]\n"

/* Range can do much more, including case-insensitive.
   The options [.anchored, .caseInsensitive] mean the search will 
   only allow a range that starts at the startIndex and 
   the comparison will be case-insensitive
*/
let filterArray2 = arrayValues.filter {
  // filters the element if foo is not found case-insensitively at the start of the element
  $0.range(of: foo, options: [.anchored, .caseInsensitive]) != nil
}


print(filterArray2) // -> "["Testy", "tester", "testing"]\n"
```

Comment: this makes a lot of sense! Thanks

Comment: I added the method `hasPrefix` to the example to show a simple case-sensitive comparison.

Comment: This should be the right answer. Except `$0` will be `!$0.`

Comment: There are no right answers, just different ways to accomplish your goal. I agree this one is more expressive than some other solutions and has the advantage that you don't have to roll your own prefix-detecting code. It's a good idea to rely on library and framework methods because they've been used, tested, and hopefully the bugs are worked out already!

Comment: I found a bug in my code, if both the prefix being tested and the string have a common prefix which is not the whole prefix being tested then it will still be true. For example, "testeroo" and "testing" both have a prefix of "test". I changed to `range(of:options:range:locale)` to remove this bug.

Comment: I like your way of observation. thumbs-up!